# Setting ENV while using Rake

Tags: ruby, rake, watir

I am using Watir/Ruby for test automation, setting my ENV Base URL using:

```
  BASE_URL = {
  :Production  => "http://prod",
  :QA => "http://qa",
  }
```

Setting my ENV using:

```
  if ENV["BASE_URL"]
      base_url = ENV["BASE_URL"]
  else
      base_url = BASE_URL[TARGET]
  end
```

Typically i change my ENV locally in my urls file, using TARGET = :Prod or :QA, depending.

I am trying to change this using while using rake, is it possible?

My Rake is setup like this in my Rakefile:

```
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:all, 'Runs all tests') do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "features/Automation/*.feature
    --format html --out=features/results/all-report-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")}.html
    --format pretty --no-source
    --format rerun --out features/results/all-rerun.txt
    --tag @regression"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An environment variable needs to be a string and would be created in a Rake file like:

```
ENV["FOO"] = "BAR"
```

I like to store configuration data like that in a yaml and then pull it out by ENV. Depending on how much data you store it is an easier way to manage it.

```
yaml = YAML.load_file('config.yml')
environment = ENV["TARGET"] || "QA"
ENV["BASE_URL"] = yaml[environment.to_sym]
```

You can also use the [fig_newton](https://github.com/cheezy/fig_newton) gem if you want something easily accessible from a class variable instead of an Environment variable.

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for, but how did you use this with Rake?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are asking. A Rake file is just Ruby code: https://github.com/sauce-examples/Capybara/blob/master/Rakefile